# iOS:CCCrypt() Which is more secure kCCOptionECBMode or kCCModeCBC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, security, encryption

```
//Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(
    kCCEncrypt,          //Operation Encrypt or Decrypt
    kCCAlgorithmAES128,  //Encrypt algorithm to be used
    kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
    keyPtr,
    kCCBlockSizeAES128,  //Key length
    nil,                 //In ECB mode ignored
    [datainput bytes],   //Data to encrypt
    dataLength,          //Length of data
    buffer,              //Data after encrypt
    bufferSize,          //Size of data after encrypt
    &numBytesEncrypted); //Onsuccess no.of bytes written
```

I have a file I want to encrypt it and I am making use of above function. Encryption and decryption is working perfectly fine!

But my concern is: there is option in cccrypt() to make use of default CBC mode or specify ECB mode. I am making use of ECB mode, so if I use CBC mode with IV then will it provide more secure encryption?

In short which one should I use default CBC mode or ECB mode? and why?

And what about IV?
does specifying IV a longer string makes encryption more secure and random?
for ECB mode it will be ignored. If i make use of CBC mode so what should be IV? please provide an example it would be helpful.

Should IV be same for encryption and decryption of same file? or can be different IV?

And what about key?
length I am using is 128, algorithm: AES

key I have used is: @"ltd@mpc"

Is it strong? or should I make use of key: 0xfedcba9876543210 something like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem and was discussed previously on [crypto.se]: [What are the advantages of CBC over ECB?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12529/13022) or [Should I use ECB or CBC encryption mode for my block cipher?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/225/13022) or [Relative merits of AES ECB and CBC modes for securing data at rest](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5405/13022)

Comment: Use "kCCKeySizeAES128" for the key length, rather than the BlockSize... they result in the same value, but really you're using the wrong constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CBC mode is more secure and the same random iv needs to be used for encryption and decrypt, it does not need to be secret. See [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for more information and a sample image.

When using a password use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 to create a random key from it.

A key length of 128 is currently fine, there is i general no reason not to use a longer key.

Consider using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it takes care of all this and adds authentication and versioning as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have written code for adding salt to key, generating random IV.